# BlackBerry TrackPad - Custom List Field with Checkbox and LableFields

Tags: blackberry

Is it possible to add checkbox in to the listfield and get the separate click event for each list item and the check boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The solution can be found in the below
>   link:

[How To - Create a ListField with check boxes](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_To_-_Create_a_ListField_with_check_boxes.html?nodeid=1165752&vernum=0)